# Angular material error when using ng-template

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-material

I want to use different UI to the navigation bar with same links using Angular material (2+).

I've tried to do it with `<ng-template>` surrounded the links with the `mat-tab-link` directive, but I got the error below in the console:

> ERROR
> Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[MatTabLink -> MatTabNav]:
> StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MatTabLink -> MatTabNav]:
> NullInjectorError: No provider for MatTabNav!

Steps to reproduce: Using the [official example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/lpymvgekdql?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftab-nav-bar-basic-example.html)

I just change the html like that:

```
<nav mat-tab-nav-bar [backgroundColor]="background">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="list"></ng-container>
</nav>

<ng-template #list>
    <a mat-tab-link *ngFor="let link of links" (click)="activeLink = link" [active]="activeLink == link"> {{link}} </a>
    <a mat-tab-link disabled>Disabled Link</a>
</ng-template>
```

Isn't the `ng-template` should render inside the `<ng-container>`?

Comment: I think `mat-tab-nav-bar` directive is not able to find the `mat-tab-link` children element due to how ng-template is being rendered on init.

Comment: @KingDarBoja I guess it close enough, but it can't be the answer... if you remove the `mat-tab-link` it not make any error.

Comment: But if you replace it by something else, like a flat link or button, it will be rendered. The issue is about the directive trying to find the child directive but it is not rendered (yet) at the time it looks for. I think it is best to not use a ng-template as angular material directives depends on what is being loaded on initialization.